# Python - Discord Rich Presence в приложении

Tags: python

Делаю приложение, и хочу туда добавить Discord Rich Presence(RPC)
Вообщем погуглил, видел только для ботов. А можно как то сделать RPC для приложения?
Тоесть я его открываю, и сразу появляется интеграция в моем аккаунте.
Буду рад всем ответам.

Comment: Так в чем проблема, вместо добавления "функционала ботов", писать нужный "функционал человеков"?

Comment: На гитхабе есть проект сам юзаю) Довольно полезная штука...
Правда я её использую для красивого вида) Надеюсь тебе подойдёт.
https://github.com/the-emerald/python-discord-rpc